# Adding numbers from a string

Tags: python-3.x

So, my problem is that I can get the numbers to print as integers, but can't get them to add together to form a one number total. right now, I am using the following code:

```
if command == 4:
      total = 0
      for item in items:
          number = (item.split()[-1])
          total += float(number)
          print(total)
```

and my output ends up being:
`2.99`
`1.87`
when I would just want:
`4.86`
it's pretty simple code, and I feel like I'm missing something fairly obvious, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Not sure why this is printing all weird, but here is a picture of the code as well[partial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a09N3.png)

The list of items is populated from user input, here is a picture of the rest of the code I am using [full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSwfA.png). I have been entering the items as 'socks, 2.99' if that helps clarifying things

Comment: Hello Everett! Unfortunately you haven't told us how you're populating the `items` list which makes it a bit difficult to understand how you're arriving at those results. Please can you show us the code before the section you've shared that populates the `items` list?

Comment: Hi @Everett  please can you provide a sample of the content of items

Comment: @JimCircadian I got that added, hopefully that helps, sorry, it's my first time using stack

Comment: @MuyideIbukun got more added on there

Comment: You are `print`ing the `total` on each iteration of the `for` loop (it's indented as part of the `for` loop). Try unindenting the print line so that it prints the total after all the iterations.

Comment: Also, post code as **text**, not as images. This would make it easier for people to copy-paste the code into their own editors to try your code out. We can't run images.

Comment: @GinoMempin perfect that did it, I knew it was going to be something small and stupid like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that you're printing the total value in each iteration, you can improve your code and do the sum in one line, just if you wanna implement and you're interested I'll let the code right here:

```
total = sum(map(float, items))
```